# Proof of continuity implied by differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to 
Let $f : (a, b) → R$ be differentiable on $(a, b)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$ by showing that:

$∀x_0 ∈ (a, b)$ $∀ε > 0$ $∃δ > 0$ s.t.

$(x ∈ (a, b), |x − x_0| < δ) ⇒ |f(x) − f(x_0)| < ε$

**My understanding so far:**

When we say a function is differentiable at $x_0$, we mean that the limit:
$$‎f^{\prime} ‎(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ exists.

When we say a function is continuous at $x_0$, we mean that:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) = 0$$

**My attempted proof:**

Let us suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$. Then
$$ \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} =  ‎f^{\prime} ‎(x) $$

and hence

$$ \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \left[ \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \right] \cdot \lim_{x\to x_0} (x-x_0) = 0$$

**My issue:**

My issue may be a non issue, however for the 6 marks this question should be worth my proof seems shallow. Could someone please poke some holes in my proof, or add to it?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe I would just add that the limit defining the derivative is *finite*, and write down the definition of $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$ at the end. The rest looks ok.

Comment: The proof as such is correct, however the task was to prove it “by showing that ($\epsilon$-$\delta$-condition)” and that's not the way you proved it.

Comment: @celtschk how would I go about proving it by showing that condition?

Comment: @celtschk I have posted an answer in terms of epsilon and sigma below. Could you please poke holes in it, change it or give it the OK please mate. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple and well-written proof. Perhaps that you could eliminate a tiny ambiguity: what is $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)-f(x_0)$? Is it $\lim_{x\to x_0}\bigl(f(x)-f(x_0)\bigr)$? Or is it $\bigl(\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\bigr)-f(x_0)$? So, your proof could begin with$$\bigl(\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\bigr)-f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\bigl(f(x)-f(x_0)\bigr)=\cdots$$If think that this is me being pedantic, tell me and I will delete this answer.

Comment: It seems to me that the question is checking whether the student can translate statements written in the limit notation to their $\epsilon $-$\delta $ definition.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: while I agree to your point, I think the solution using limit laws as offered by OP is more elegant than using $\epsilon, \delta$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: However in homework, you generally get points for doing the tasks you are asked to do, not for elegant ways to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and $a$ arbitrarily.

From the definition of differentiation we have
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a)\right| < \varepsilon
$$

for an appropriately chosen $\delta > 0$.

Multiply both sides by $|x - a|$ to get:
$$
\left|f(x) - f(a) - (x - a)f'(a)\right| < |x - a| \varepsilon
$$

Using the reverse triangle rule, $\left||x|-|y|\right| \le |x - y|$, we have:

$$
\left|f(x) - f(a)\right| - |x - a| \cdot \left|f'(a)\right|  < |x - a| \varepsilon
$$

Wbhich we rearrange to get:
$$
\left|f(x) - f(a)\right| < (\left|f'(a)\right| + \varepsilon) \cdot |x - a|
$$

Since $f'(a)$ and $\varepsilon$ are both fixed, you can make $|f(x) - f(a)|$ as small as you want by making $|x - a|$ smaller and smaller. Thus, the function is continuous at $a$.

To prove this formally, pick any $\hat{\varepsilon}$ (different from $\varepsilon$ fixed at the beginning and used with the differentiation definition). Pick $\hat{\delta} = \min\left(\delta, \frac{\hat{\varepsilon}}{\left|f'(a)\right| + \varepsilon}\right)$. Clearly:

$$
|x - a| < \hat{\delta} \Rightarrow \left|f(x) - f(a)\right| < \hat{\varepsilon}
$$

End Proof.

Comment: The second sentence makes no sense as written: The statement that you say depends on a suitably chosen $\delta$ mentions no $\delta$ anywhere.

Comment: Although it is probably fine, it may be even better to write the reverse triangle inequality as $|x|-|y|\le||x|-|y||\le|x-y|$. And even better still if you also remind the reader that $|ab|=|a|\cdot|b|$.

Comment: The final paragraph is the key one, and it is clunky as written, since you have not explained how $\varepsilon$ depends on $\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct, but you might be a little relieved to use the other equivalent definition of a derivative $$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

Use $f(x+h) - f(x) = h \cdot \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$, then we have

$$\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h) - f(x) = (\lim_{h \to 0} h )\cdot f'(x) = 0 \cdot f'(x) = 0 \implies \lim_{h\to0} f(x+h) = f(x)$$

Comment: This is not written in the $\epsilon $-$\delta $ language, which is what the question wants to evaluate.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo could you please elaborate on how I would answer the question using the $\epsilon \sigma$ language. The proof as it stands makes sense to me and I cans see where or how to implement the required notation. Thank you

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I have posted an answer in terms of epsilon and sigma below. Could you please poke holes in it, change it or give it the OK please mate. Thank you :)